# What political power does a Kage have?

Tags: naruto

I know that, in Naruto, Kages (such as the Hokage) run the hidden villages (such as Konoha). There are, however, also other people in the world with political powers, such as feudal lords. What political power does a Kage have as opposed to one of the other political leaders in the world? To further that question, where in the hierarchy of all of the political people in the world do they fall? To clarify, do they answer to anybody or command any other political leaders, and if so, in what regards?

Comment: Good question, i have always wondered this too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "Kage" is not used to just refer to any leader of any village it's only for the leaders of the Five Great Shinobi Countries. Their responsibilities include:

- To oversee the ninja activity in the village.
- To prepare and send ninjas to the active missions.
- Organize the ninja promotion exams (chuunin exam).
- Manage the rewards of the mission and distribute it as a payment for the ninjas.

A village is ruled by 2 political and 1 military power. You have the Feudal Lords, the Elders and the Kage. The Kage, before taking any big decisions that will involve the entire village (activities not only ninja-related), for example safety issues (***What to do with Naruto***), have to discuss it with the Feudal Lords and the Elders. In other words, the Kage is the biggest title a ninja can get, but regarding the administration of the village, it has to be discussed with the **Elders** and of course the owners of the land and possibly of the economy: the **Feudal Lords**.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, but I'm just wondering where you found this information.

Comment: @kuwaly wacthing Naruto since the very beginning... i could add some links but dude is gonna take me some time haha ;)

Comment: Ah. I wasn't sure if you had gotten it from some source or some particular chapters.

Comment: Well i have some particular chapters in mind. But right now i do not remember which number are they :(. If you need it to have a better answer let me look for them but is going to take me some time :)

Comment: If you can think of the chapters, I would like to see them, but I'll accept it without them. I'm going to wait to see if there is another answer, but if there isn't a better answer (and I don't think there will be), I'll accept it.

Comment: The ninja villages don't have Feudal lords. The Kage and the village (ninja) Elders are the sole powers in a ninja village. It is shown that while a Kage is the ultimate head of the ninja village, they have to respect the Elders (presumably because of the Elders collected political powers and ninja skills/experience) creating an every changing power balance in a villages politics.

Comment: To carry this just a bit further, the Feudal lords rule everything but the ninja villages. This means that the ninja villages need very good relations with their nation's feudal lords to get cooperation (ie, trade), peace (no feudal lord armies attacking/harassing them), and large value paying jobs. So even the most minor of all the local feudal lords will be treated with great respect by the ninjas from the villages in the interest of continued peace and harmony.